# Does Switch need its own MAC address?

Tags: switch, mac-address, spanning-tree, mac

I saw a post say Switch do not need its MAC address, unless it's an administrable Switch for managing.

but I found the spanning-tree protocol need a MAC address of Switch to form STP Root Bridge ID.

so, is the switch always need a MAC address? 
nevertheless in a two layer circuit, all the Switch need a self MAC address at least?

Comment: On Cisco, all interfaces including SVI's have burned in MAC addresses.

Comment: @Cown I mean, except the interfaces and SVI, is the Switch still need MAC address?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The basic function of a switch is transparent bridging - for this, it doesn't need any MAC address of its own.

However, if you need to talk to a switch - ie. a *managed switch* - then that switch requires an address; usually that is a MAC address and an IP address [*]. STP is only supported on managed switches and in addition, an STP bridge is required to have a unique bridge ID which usually is identical to the management MAC address.

[*] A managed network device could just have a serial console which doesn't require any addressing. However, this was only used on very early devices. Today, most devices feature both, in-band network management and out-of-band console access.

Comment: I have a question, in a switch STP circuit, can there have a `non-manage` Switch?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I have never seen an unmanaged switch supporting STP. Without a console, you wouldn't be able to set the STP priorities. With STP, that unmanaged switch would be required to have a MAC address as well.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if your switch supports spanning-tree protocol(either legacy spanning tree protocol, rapid-pvst+ or MST) your switch will have a mac address since spanning-tree protocol uses bridgeID to elect the root bridge and bridgeID consists of the bridge-Priority, a unique mac address and system-id which is basically the vlan number.

Also if a switch has a management ip address, it will need to have a mac address so that ethernet frames can be forwarded to it at layer 2.

Comment: Is there 1 MAC address per switch port? Or one MAC address per device?

Answer (score 0):

The MAC address used by the spanning tree algorithm (STA) implemented in a given switch does not belong to any of its Ethernet interfaces. At least in Cisco implementations, this MAC address is known as *base MAC* or *universal (burned-in) MAC* and its purpose is to identify the switch itself, not some of its Ethernet interfaces. For this reason, this MAC address is printed on a label attached on the back of the device.

You can check a device's base MAC by issuing the *show version* command:

> SW1#show version Cisco IOS Software, C2960 Software (C2960-LANBASE-M),
> Version 12.2(25)FX, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1) Copyright (c) 1986-2005 by
> Cisco Systems, Inc. Compiled Wed 12-Oct-05 22:05 by pt_team
>
> ROM: C2960 Boot Loader (C2960-HBOOT-M) Version 12.2(25r)FX, RELEASE
> SOFTWARE (fc4)
>
> System returned to ROM by power-on
>
> Cisco WS-C2960-24TT (RC32300) processor (revision C0) with 21039K
> bytes of memory.
>
> 24 FastEthernet/IEEE 802.3 interface(s) 2 Gigabit Ethernet/IEEE 802.3
> interface(s)
>
> 63488K bytes of flash-simulated non-volatile configuration memory.
>
> **Base ethernet MAC Address       : 0001.43BA.DE15**
>
> Motherboard assembly number     : 73-9832-06 Power supply part number        :
>
> 341-0097-02 Motherboard serial number       : FOC103248MJ Power supply
>
> serial number      : DCA102133JA Model revision number           : B0
>
> Motherboard revision number     : C0 Model number                    :
>
> WS-C2960-24TT System serial number            : FOC1033Z1EY Top
>
> Assembly Part Number        : 800-26671-02 Top Assembly Revision
>
> Number    : B0 Version ID                      : V02
> CLEI Code Number : COM3K00BRA
>
> Hardware Board Revision Number  : 0x01

You can read more on this [here](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/s/question/0D53i00000Kt67u/stp-what-is-the-source-of-mac-address-in-bridge-id-details)